# Marketing Cloud Literal Content API Search

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, content-builder, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to use the Marketing Cloud Rest API to search content for a literal string. For example “make my day”. When I submit my request using Postman I receive a response that has content that includes each individual word rather the entire phrase.

How can I perform a literal content query?

If I submit the followingent body as a POST I get "bootcamp" and "OTC". How can I just jet OTC with a space on either side of the search value?

POST `https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/query`

```
{ "page": { "page": 1, "pageSize": 50 }, 
"query": { "property": "content", "simpleOperator": "mustcontain", "value": "OTC" }, 
"fields": [ "AssetType", "Views", "Content" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [Simple Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetSimpleQuery.htm) and adding all your filters directly to the GET request URL:

```
https://[your_domain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets?$page=1&$pagesize=50&$filter=Content%20like%20'%20OTC%20'&$fields=AssetType,Views,Content
```

The main filter here would be `Content%20like%20'%20OTC%20'`, which would search for content that has the " OTC " part (with two before and after spaces that are represented by "%20"). This way you would skip "bootcamp" values.